# Issues creating view with 2 joins

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create a view that contains 2 joins for using a total of 3 tables. I keep getting: #1064 telling me I have a syntax error. However, I have been following what different guides and solutions say to do. Apparently, I am missing something.

I've done research on creating views for MySQL using joins and 3 tables, proper syntax of joins.

```
create view vw_interns_complete_training AS
select i.first_name, i.last_name, i.intern_id, inT.training_ID, 
t.training, t.completed
from intern as i
inner join intern_training as inT on i.intern_ID = inT.intern_ID 
inner join training as t On inT.training_ID = t.training_ID
where completed = 1;
```

The expected output is an successfully created join. The results are:
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inT on i.intern_ID = inT.intern_ID 
 inner join training as t On inT.training_ID' at line 4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should nou use a INT as table name alias  INT (inT)  is a reseved   word
better change with inT with eg: it

```
create view vw_interns_complete_training AS
select i.first_name
  , i.last_name
  , i.intern_id
  , it.training_ID
  , t.training
  , t.completed
from intern as i
inner join intern_training as it on i.intern_ID = it.intern_ID 
inner join training as t On it.training_ID = t.training_ID
where t.completed = 1;
```